# In Azure portal, how can I monitor, report or query on the number of PaaS App Service Instances running over previous day or week?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-monitoring

Does anyone know how to report on the number of PaaS/App Service instances that were running over the last day or week?

I can see real-time/current instance count under the Scale Out pane/blade however I cannot seem to find where I can check what the instance count was over last 24 hours or week.

I'm trying to determine why the instance count jumped from default to increased number of instances when there is no activity?

I've noticed this before and restarting the App Service resets things back to defaults however having some way to track and notify when Instance Count is above a threshold would be great.

Answer (score 0):

To know the number of instances run via Scale-out feature in the Azure App Service, view the **Run History**.

[image]

Auto-Scaling should be enabled to see the number of instances changed using Run History. If Auto-Scaling is not enabled, you will see only the current instance status in [Process Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/updates/manage-your-azure-websites-directly-with-websites-process-explorer/) of the Azure App Service.

Also, you can see the logs in Activity Log about more details in Run history which clearly says about how many instances the [Auto-Scaling feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/autoscale/autoscale-understanding-settings?toc=/azure/azure-monitor/toc.json) initiated:

[image]

Refer to this [Monitoring your multiple Azure App Service instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/waws/monitoring-your-multiple-azure-web-app-instances)

Comment: Thank you very much, that is the information I was looking for.  I will check out your Monitoring link as well  Once again, thank you very much for your help on this.  Cheers!!